# cy.load() elements are lost

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to store the current graph in browser on the server side and now I'm testing how to. I ran into a strange Problem: after jsoning, decycling, stringifying and reloading the graph, the elements are somehow lost.

```
var j = network_tab.cy.json();
j = JSON.decycle(j);
j = JSON.stringify(j);
network_tab.cy.load(j);
```

Before decycling the graph, I cannot stringify it. If you look in the stringified version, you can see, that the elements are still there, but after loading, they are gone.

Maybe I have a problem in general with the cy.load() function, but I do hope you guys can help me.

EDIT: The problem seems to be with the stringify function. Then my question boils down how to make the whole object readable for load().

```
 An element must be of type `nodes` or `edges`; you specified `undefined`   
 console.error( msg );
 cytoscape.js (line 244)
 TypeError: obj._private is undefined
```

I want to copy the whole thing, but especially the elements, the positions.
So is it better to reinitialize the graph completely and when so, how do I add the positions of the nodes?

Answer (score 1):

(1) cy.json() is undocumented (and probably not ready for use) until 2.1

(2) You shouldn't need to use `JSON.decycle()` unless your own data that you're putting in elements have references to one another -- not a good idea in general.

(3) cy.json() gives you the whole graph state as used in intialisation -- not for `cy.load()`.  You could pass `json.elements` to `cy.load()` but not the root object, `json`.

(4) You can alternatively get each individual element as JSON via (the tested and documented prior to 2.1) `ele.json()` and build your own object to pass to `cy.load()`.

(5) Have you inspected the object you're passing to `cy.load()`?  Can you post it here?  You're not passing a JSON string to `cy.load()`, are you?

Comment: I tried to parse the whole cy.json() object, but that obviously didn't work. Now I'm trying to parse cy.json().elements to load, and everything works, but the positions. So I probably have to to completely reinitialize the graph and there I can add the positions?

Comment: When calling `cy.load()`, remember that a layout is called along with it -- as opposed to `cy.add()` which uses the element-specified positions.  So, you need to use a preset layout or similar, or you need to use `cy.add()`. Docs: http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/