# Exporting and importing JSON data to Cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, json, cytoscape.js

Based on [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113119/cy-load-elements-are-lost/21119797#21119797), I've made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3d3K/).

What I'm trying to do is to find a way to properly export / import JSON data to cytoscape.js.

I'm using `JSON.stringify(cy.json())` to get JSON data from elements, and on the other hand I'm cleaning the `cy` area and using `cy.add(text-input)` to add the elements back.

I.e.: you can add a node, copy it's JSON data generated, then you can refresh the browser and paste the JSON data from node directly, tryng to add it to `cy`.

But I couldn't get this to work, and I can't really figure out where I'm wrong (probably using the `cy.add` function). Always geting both errors:

`An element must be of type 'nodes' or 'edges'; you specified 'undefined'`

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'single' of undefined`

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you build from the source (or use 2.1 when released), you can use `eles.jsons()`, which gives an array of element JSONs.  You're calling `cy.json()`, which gives the entire graph init options JSON -- which you can't pass to `cy.add()` or similar.

Alternatively to `eles.jsons()`, you can use the already existing `ele.json()` and build up an array yourself by iterating over the elements.

You also need to pass the objects to `cy.add()` etc.  You can't pass a JSON string.

e.g.

```
cy.add( JSON.parse( jsonString ) )
```

Comment: Thanks, once again. I'd just make zip from 2.1 and `cy.elements().jsons()` works pretty well.